# EntityFrameworkCore guarda automáticamente objetos en Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, blazor

Tal vez no esté entendiendo bien como funcionan algunas cosas en Blazor, ya que lo que me sucede no tiene lógica para mi.

### Tengo 2 componentes:

```
@page "/users"
```

*Muestra listado de usuarios con opciones de eliminar o editar.*

---

```
@page "user/edit/{id}"
```

*Formulario con un EditForm e InputText con sus respectivos @bind-Value="user.Value" para el objeto User.*

```
@code
{
    [Parameter] public string id { get; set; }
    Useruser = new User();
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        person = await UserService.GetByIdAsync(id);
    }
}
```

---

Hasta ahí todo funciona correctamente.

---

### El problema

Cuando modifico algún campo de texto, y vuelvo hacia atrás en el navegador, o voy hacia otra página, **pero sin darle a guardar cambios**, el objeto aparece modificado con los valores que yo escribí en los inputs. No sé si sea un bug, o si esté no entendiendo cómo funciona esto, pero lleva lugar a muchas confusiones al tratar de trabajar con algo así.

Incluso agregué un breakpoint en `UserService.GetByIdAsync()` para fijarme qué objetos estaba trayendo desde la base de datos, e incluso ahí también se veía modificado el objeto. Pero corroborando en la tabla en SqlServerManagementStudio no se ve aplicada la modificación, lo cual hizo que aún más me confunda y no sepa por dónde buscarle la solución a esto.
También probé descargarme algún proyecto de gente que hace tutoriales de Blazor, un simple CRUD, y también está el mismo problema, y nadie parece notarlo.
También probé si sucedía esto en un proyecto Asp Net MVC y no, no sucede.

Espero alguien pueda darme una mano, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si entendí bien el problema, pero eso puede surgir debido a que si el input está bindeado  con un atributo del objeto, esto provoca que al modificar el input modifiques el objeto. No me queda muy claro como actualizas el estado del objeto entre los componentes. Además otro problema es que puede ser es que llamas al método para obtener al usuario lo haces en el ciclo de vida parameter set, tendrías que probar hacerlo en el OnAfteRrender cuando es el primer renderizado para que obtenga los datos cada vez que se renderice la página por primera vez.